# Fixing drift in a recursive fixed point filter

Tags: moving-average, fixed-point

I'm implementing a 80-72-64-48 multi pass moving average filter for a embedded system in C and in fixed point. The implementation is a circular buffer where i'm keeping a running sum and calculating

$$ y[n] = y[n-1] + x[n] - x[n-M] $$ where $M$ is the length of a filter. This is done for each subfilter with the output from one serving as the input for another.

I'm scaling my coefficients by $2^{15}$ which gives me coefficients of length $2^{9}$ or $2^{10}$ depending on the filter length. Then the result is scaled down again by $2^{-15}$ to get the correct output.

Now, everything looks good on short time scales but over long times i get a drift. The reason for the recursive implementation is to save calculations on a embedded processor.

I have included image of some of the internals of my filter, this is when a step response is applied and we can see the transfer functions of the filters taking shape, square, triangle, then approximating a gaussian so the filter is working as expected.

[image: Internals]

Now here is my problem, the  drift 
[image]

Is there any way to fix this, and where is the most likely source of this?, is this drift due to a bit getting lost in the shifting or something else. The drift is not present for DC inputs, but for AC signals it slowly drifts.

SOLUTION: The problem was in the accumulator as robert suggested in the comments. The issue was that one element of the calculation had gone through an extra up and down shift compared to the rest, which created a round offset that accumulated.

Comment: is your accumulator $y[n]$ being rounded or quantized in any manner?  you must make sure that the $x[n-M]$ that is subtracted is exactly the same value as $x[n]$ that was added $M$ samples ago.  so you really want to do a moving **sum**, rather than a moving average and scale the output of your moving sum (with $1/M$) to get you the average.  this is quite doable and even better done in fixed-point rather than floating-point.

Comment: "Scaling the coefficients"? I assume that you divide by $M$ after each stage and that is the coefficient which you scale? That is probably the cause of the offset. Better then to divide by $\prod M_i$ at the end of all filters. You need to keep track of the internal amplitudes though as you will eventually overflow the accumulators. However, this is easily solved through modulo arithmetic (of which two's complement is a special case).

Comment: Oscar, this is a fixed point filter. Meaning i only do integer arithmetic. For a moving average of length > 1 with gain 1 the filter constants will be a fraction which is not representable in integers. So the coefficients are scaled to make them integers by left shifting them x many bits. Because of this the final output has to be shifted as well to the right by as many bits.I cannot keep a running sum through all 4 filters without restoring the output in between, the input signal is 16 bits and with the coefficient scaling and lengths a single filter uses my entire accumulator space of 32 bit

Comment: The problem was in the accumulator as robert suggested. The issue was that one element of the calculation had gone through an extra up and down shift compared to the rest, which created a offset.